# Downloaded files disappearing on update

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pdf

I have an app that downloads several pdfs and images. It all work perfectly fine, I store information of those files in core data. My problem comes when I send out updates of the app, all the information in core data is transferred to the new version correctly but the files are nowhere to be found.

I guess I can write a routine to run when users update the app and download the files all over again. I just believe there is a better way to go by preserving the files.

Has anybody experience on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the files in the Documents dir, there they will be not deleted unless you remove the app from the device.

Comment: I am adding "Documents" to the path, but for some reason they still get deleted when updating versions of the app.

Comment: What functions do you use to download and store?

Comment: writeToFile from NSData and simply pass the filepath. As for downloading, I simply download from a URL to the NSData object.

Comment: Can you check in the simulator, where the files are stored?

Comment: ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhoneSimulator/4.3.2/Applications/ApplicationID/Documents/Filename.pdf

Comment: I've learned that the path to the doc-dir on the device can change with an update, existing files will be moved. Can you rebuild the paths by calling NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains and extract the new docir?